# Screen freezes on connecting to mongodb in Windows 10

Tags: windows, mongodb

I was trying to set up mongo server on Windows 10.

[image]

It looked like everything alright and the service was listening on 27017.

However on another command prompt, `mongo` failed to connect and the screen just froze as follow

[image]

I've checked the firewall rule, port 27017 is open. And ping 127.0.0.1 is responding.

Any idea why the connection would get stuck?

Comment: This is not on topic for Stack Overflow. It might be a much better fit to open an issue on GitHub (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Try running mongo.exe with verbose mode

```
c:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe --verbose
```

This will help you diagnose this further.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got this situation.

Solution: Edit mongo configuration

> mongodb.conf
>   linux: `sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf`

and disable `auth=true`. Then restart mongo server service.

```
linux: sudo service mongodb restart
```

Incorrect config authentication steps lead to this hanging in mongo shell.
After that, config following this link: https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8

Then re-enable `auth=true`